# how to retrieve sub child values having same names from firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

my viewHolder class

```
public TextView textAreaName,textAreaTotalCount,textAreaAvailCount;
public itemClickListener listener;
public AreaViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
{
    super(itemView);
    textAreaName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.area_area_name);
    textAreaTotalCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.area_total_count);
    textAreaAvailCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.area_avail_count);
}

public void setItemClickListener(itemClickListener listener)
{
    this.listener=listener;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    listener.onClick(v,getAdapterPosition(),false);
}
```

my model class

```
public class ComplexModel {
    private String complex_name,complex_id,area_count,area_id,total_count,available_count,slot;

    public ComplexModel(String complex_name, String complex_id, String area_count, String area_id, String total_count, String available_count, String slot) {
        this.complex_name = complex_name;
        this.complex_id = complex_id;
        this.area_count = area_count;
        this.area_id = area_id;
        this.total_count = total_count;
        this.available_count = available_count;
        this.slot = slot;
    }

    public String getComplex_name() {
        return complex_name;
    }

    public void setComplex_name(String complex_name) {
        this.complex_name = complex_name;
    }

    public String getComplex_id() {
        return complex_id;
    }

    public void setComplex_id(String complex_id) {
        this.complex_id = complex_id;
    }

    public String getArea_count() {
        return area_count;
    }

    public void setArea_count(String area_count) {
        this.area_count = area_count;
    }

    public String getArea_id() {
        return area_id;
    }

    public void setArea_id(String area_id) {
        this.area_id = area_id;
    }

    public String getTotal_count() {
        return total_count;
    }

    public void setTotal_count(String total_count) {
        this.total_count = total_count;
    }

    public String getAvailable_count() {
        return available_count;
    }

    public void setAvailable_count(String available_count) {
        this.available_count = available_count;
    }

    public String getSlot() {
        return slot;
    }

    public void setSlot(String slot) {
        this.slot = slot;
    }

    public ComplexModel() {
    }
}
```

this is the code that i tried to get the values from the database

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_park_area);

    complexName = getIntent().getStringExtra("complexname");
    cID = getIntent().getStringExtra("cID");

    reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(cID);

    jAreaList = findViewById(R.id.areaList);
    jAreaList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    jtv3 = findViewById(R.id.tv3);
    jComplexName = findViewById(R.id.area_complex_name);

    jComplexName.setText(complexName);
}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ComplexModel> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ComplexModel>()
            .setQuery(reff.orderByChild("slot"),ComplexModel.class)
            .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ComplexModel,AreaViewHolder> adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ComplexModel, AreaViewHolder>(options)
            {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AreaViewHolder holder, int i, @NonNull ComplexModel complexModel)
        {
            holder.textAreaName.setText(complexModel.getArea_id());
            holder.textAreaTotalCount.setText(complexModel.getTotal_count());
            holder.textAreaAvailCount.setText(complexModel.getAvailable_count());

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    startActivity(new Intent(ParkAreaActivity.this,ReservationActivity.class));
                }
            });
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public AreaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.area_item_layout,parent,false);
            AreaViewHolder holder = new AreaViewHolder(view);
            return holder;
        }
    };
    jAreaList.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
}
```

This is format of my firebase database structure. I want to retrieve the values of `slot,available_count` and `total_count` from both of sub child.

my structure of values stored in firebase database

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF7T2.png)

Comment: Have you tried anything in code?

Comment: yes sir.. i've tried to view this values using firebase recycler adapter

Comment: Please add your code that you tried

Comment: i am added my code sir

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo in this i cant't able to retrieve the values of parking_area1 and 2

Comment: @SathaSivam Please add a more detailed screenshot of your database.

Comment: @AlexMamo ok sir i added it

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object `ParkingArea` with those values as parameters and then when fetching from db, create objects based on values from there, put them to the list that will be used in Your adapter

Some docs [Firebase write / read data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)